# Content Security Policy for LinkedIn Share Button

Tags: linkedin-api, content-security-policy

I'm currently trying to add the LinkedIn share button to my site, with the `<script type="IN/Share"></script>` tag. However I have a fairly strong Content Security Policy and it looks like it requires an `unsafe-inline` for both `style-src` and `script-src` which is obviously something I'm not prepared to do as I might as well just not have a CSP at that point.

Does anyone know a way of getting the share button to display correctly without having to enable these?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either use a nonce or sha hash. If it's just the Linkedin plugin and the code is the same on every page (like I hope it would be), you just need the sha hash included with your existing directives, something like:

`script-src: 'sha-35443567457455424532765'`

Google Chrome will generate sha hashes for you in the dev tools, just copy the strings it gives you for the resources you need to load, reload with the new CSP and confirm if it works. Test multiple pages to be sure it covers all cases.

Using sha can get messy if you have code that adds a large amount of inline style/scripts, but if it's a single widget like this it should only take one/a few. The exact sha hash will change as Linkedin's code changes (and may even depend on variables set when creating the button) so I haven't included an exact hash as it'd be unlikely to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this easily using https://sharingbuttons.io

Here is a Share button for LinkedIn. Replace MY_URL and MY_TEXT with your strings.

```html
<!-- Sharingbutton LinkedIn -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=MY_URL&amp;title=MY_TEXT&amp;summary=MY_TEXT&amp;source=MY_URL" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Share on LinkedIn">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--linkedin resp-sharing-button--large"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solidcircle">
    <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M12,0C5.383,0,0,5.383,0,12s5.383,12,12,12s12-5.383,12-12S18.617,0,12,0z M9.5,16.5h-2v-7h2V16.5z M8.5,7.5 c-0.553,0-1-0.448-1-1c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1s1,0.448,1,1C9.5,7.052,9.053,7.5,8.5,7.5z M18.5,16.5h-3V13c0-0.277-0.225-0.5-0.5-0.5 c-0.276,0-0.5,0.223-0.5,0.5v3.5h-3c0,0,0.031-6.478,0-7h3v0.835c0,0,0.457-0.753,1.707-0.753c1.55,0,2.293,1.12,2.293,3.296V16.5z" />
    </svg>
    </div>Share on LinkedIn</div>
</a>
```